# How to echo COUNT number in select statement mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to know how to echo the COUNT in the select statement. I want to tell user how many user is match. something like    $count=COUNT(user_id); echo $count;

```html
<?php
$stm =$db->prepare("SELECT user FROM tabe WHERE id=1 GROUP BY user_id order by COUNT(user_id) DESC ");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user,COUNT(user_id) as usercount FROM tabe WHERE id=1 GROUP BY user_id order by usercount DESC
```